# Error when Importing WordPress Database from localhost A to localhost B

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

I have been building my WordPress website locally with "Laptop A". 
But now I want to use "Laptop B" to continue building my website locally, so I will need to reinstall WordPress and import my database and theme into Laptop B.

For Laptop A, I went to phpmyadmin and exported my Database, and saved the file as wptest.sql

For Laptop B, I installed MAMP, I went to phpmyadmin, created a new database, installed WordPress, created another database, imported that same sql file into the newer database, and updated the DB_NAME in wp-config.php

Problem is the database from Laptop A is NOT recognized in Laptop B. In other words, if I go to localhost:8888/wordpress I am taken to a page to install WordPress (see image below).
The reverse is also an issue. Database from Laptop B is NOT recognized in Laptop A.

However, I can successfully export/import a database WITHIN Laptop A.
And, I can successfully export/import a database WITHIN Laptop B.
Therefore the sql file is not corrupt.

The problem is importing a database from Laptop A to B --and -- from Laptop B to A, results in the WordPress Install page. What could be the problem? I am a newbie so let me know if I missed a step.

Laptop A
OS: Windows XP
Localhost: Uniserver Zero XI

Laptop B
OS: Macbook 10.5.8
Localhost: MAMP 1.9.6.1

[image]

**EDIT**

**Fabio is correct, the issue is indeed the $table_prefix.** However, Laptop B is not working because MAMP is acting weird. When I create a new database in Laptop B, it causes the MySQL Server in MAMP to shut down (but Apache Server continues to run).

The "Activity Monitor" (in Apple > Applications > Utilities) shows a bunch of mysqld processes running. I am able to Force Quit all mysqld processes except for one. I quit MAMP and there is still a mysqld process running in the Activity Monitor.

Is it because I am using an old version of MAMP from 2011? I can't use the new version of MAMP cause it does not work with my old ancient Mac 10.5.8

I do not understand, why would creating a new database (and updating the DB_NAME) trigger the MySQL server of MAMP to shut down?

And how many mysqld processes should actually be running?
.

Comment: while it's hard to tell, my best bet is you probably have an existing WP database in Laptop B, therefore you have to change the $table_prefix line in wp-config.php from wp_ to whatever prefix you want and it will work.

Comment: Hmm this did not work. I changed Latop B's $table_prefix in wp-config.php to the same prefix as Laptop A, but same problem. Let me know if I missed any other steps. (Do I need to register the table prefix or something? Or simply changing the prefix in wp-config.php is sufficient ?)

Comment: I don't know if that's the problem, but assuming it is, just change wp_ to (say) xy_ and see if it works. It should be enough. The fact that yo can import tells me that you already have a DB, so I'm betting that is the issue. Otherwise, don't know without seeing it

Comment: @Fabio you were right, prefix is the issue. But Laptop B is not working because of issues with MAMP, can you check out my question in my edit?

Comment: glad to help. I really don't know MAMP so can't tell about these processes. Also, this is a different question and not related to WP, SQL or PHPMyAdmin, so I strongly recommend you to create a new question with the new info so you get more views from people who have more knowledge on the subject.